# Change text image on real image

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

I use pnotify to notice on website.

I want to put image on the notice, but just I can't do this.

```
var image = new Array("image 1", "image 2", "image 3");
```

This work's. Show me just text image 1, but i want that notice show image.
I want change text image 1 on real image.

Can you help me ?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWrYEo

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an html to the `text` property of pnotify.

```
$.pnotify({ text: "<img src='image-url.jpg'/>" });
```